# Desesperately trying to run raspbian buster on qemu, hangs on black screen

Tags: qemu, raspbian-buster

This is my command:
`sudo qemu-system-arm \ -kernel kernel-qemu-4.14.79-stretch \ -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \ -drive if=none,format=raw,file=2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img \ -cpu arm1176 -m 256 \ -M versatilepb \ -no-reboot \ -serial stdio \ -net nic -net user \ -net tap,ifname=vnet0,script=no,downscript=no`

Normally, this makes qemu just freeze at "guest has not initialized display yet" and it gives an error that says the machine ID is not recognized for some reason, so if I try replacing versatilepb with raspi2, qemu just freezes at a black screen, I also tried using the buster kernel and the stretch image and nothing, this is driving me insane, could anyone give me advice? I'm new to qemu and I really want to use a raspberry VM.

Comment: try posting this on https://superuser.com

Comment: Unrecognized machine ID means that either that kernel image is not compiled to support the versatilepb machine you're running it on, or that the kernel requires you to also pass QEMU the correct DTB via the -dtb option. Unless you like trying to debug "board bringup/bootup" problems, I recommend that you find a known-working tutorial for this and follow it.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641518/qemu-showing-as-black-screen-for-arm-vm though the only answer there doesn't give the actual fix (add a -dtb option), that's in one of the comments.

Comment: PS: quoting the exact error message rather than paraphrasing it helps a lot for getting good answers.